# Cant add ganache network (running on windows) on metamask (from android) when broadcasting over 0.0.0.0:7545, says cant fetch chain id, check rpc url

Tags: metamask, ganache

i am running ganache on my windows machine and have configured my RPC server to listen on 0.0.0.0, but i am not being able to add the network on my metamask wallet in phone

[image]

RPC URL in metamask app i entered is http://{my-local-windows-ip}:7545
chain id 1337
on adding i get the error :-

**Could not fetch chainId, is your RPC-URL correct ?**